# Manually rotate the coordinate system for landscape mode left

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgaffinetransform

I am aware that the upper left corner of the screen (assuming phone is held in landscape left) is (0,0). However, if I wanted my (0,0) point to be the bottom left corner instead of the upper left corner, how would I do it?

I'm trying to draw objects using OpenGL in the specified location I am currently touching on the screen but the y value is being drawn on the wrong side of the screen. Heres a picture example of the issue if it helps. Note that the whited out spot is where I 'touch' the screen and the purple stuff is the particle system I am drawing using OpenGL.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/n2lhzfdbp4audi2/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20shot%20Apr%2023%2C%202013%206.25.49%20PM.png

https://www.dropbox.com/s/foueopvlgfu03vs/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20shot%20Apr%2023%2C%202013%206.25.53%20PM.png

I set my supported interface like this:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication*)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow*)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
```

In my `drawFrame` method:

```
glViewport(0, 0, 480, 320);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

glOrthof(0.0f, 480, 0.0f, 320, -100.0f, 100.0f);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

//render the particles being drawn, etc
```

In my `touchesBegan` method:

```
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

if (pe.active != YES)
{
    pe.active = YES;

    NSLog(@"x: %f y: %f", location.x, location.y);

    pe.sourcePosition = Vector2fMake(location.x, location.y);
}
```

I then tried to manually rotate the coordinate system 90 degrees by doing this in my `viewWillAppear` method:

```
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((M_PI * (-90) / 180.0));
self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480, 320);
```

Specifying `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` call with -90 degrees as shown above should alter the coordinate system but it doesn't.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any OpenGL. Change the coordinate system when drawing.

Comment: Ive edited my question and added pictures to better explain my issue, thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In general, you should avoid setting a VC's view frame, bounds, and transform. These are automatically set by UIKit to handle things like rotation and resizing (e.g. for the in-call status bar).

There are two simple fixes:

- Transform the touch points (`location.x, height-location.y`)
- Use a top-left origin in the projection matrix (`glOrthof(0, width, height, 0, ...)`). You might have to worry about the handedness of the coordinate system.

I currently prefer the second option: Things are much less messy when there are as few coordinate systems in use as possible.

Other minor issues

- You should use the actual width and height instead of hard-coding 320 and 480. Remember to check on "Retina" and "Retina 4-inch" as well.
- `self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;` is pointless since you immediately clobber it with a write. on the next line.

---

If you *really need* to set the transform of the view, make it a *subview* of the VC's view. Also note that some views don't work properly if you set their transform (e.g. `UITableView` on some versions of iOS uses its frame to decide how wide cells should be when it should use its bounds). It's not uncommon to need a view structure like this:

- Outer container (whose frame/transform is set by e.g. UIKit)

  - Inner container (this is where you set the transform)

    - The actual view you care about (e.g. `UITableView`) whose transform you do not set.

Needless to say, I try to avoid this whenever possible.

Comment: Perfect solution! I swapped the glorthof like you suggested and it works great, can't believe I missed that. Yeah, the 320 and 480 hardcoded in was just because I was in a hurry but Im going to definitely change it. Thanks a bunch